# Console.log('variable') - how to show

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here I have a function `route();`

```
function route() {
      // Clear any previous route boxes from the map
      clearBoxes();

      // Convert the distance to box around the route from miles to km
      distance = parseFloat(document.getElementById("distance").value) * 1.609344;

      var request = {
        origin: document.getElementById("from").value,
        destination: document.getElementById("to").value,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      }
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
  directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
  var route = response.routes[0];
  startLocation = new Object();
  endLocation = new Object();

  var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
  var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
  for (i=0;i<legs.length;i++) {
    if (i == 0) { 
      startLocation.latlng = legs[i].start_location;
      startLocation.address = legs[i].start_address;
    }
    endLocation.latlng = legs[i].end_location;
    endLocation.address = legs[i].end_address;
  }
      }
      // Make the directions request
      directionService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);

          // Box around the overview path of the first route
          var path = result.routes[0].overview_path;
          var boxes = routeBoxer.box(path, distance);
          drawBoxes(boxes);
        } else {
          alert("Directions query failed: " + status);
        }
      });
    }
```

this function create a route direction between two places and put 2 markers on map (start Point marker and end Point marker)

Now I want to use this marker position in other function and to show in console.log to see what happend with my code.

I try:

```
console.log(startLocation.latlng);
```

but then I get in console:

```
ReferenceError: startLocation is not defined
get stack: function () { [native code] }
message: "startLocation is not defined"
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error
```

How I can show this start and end latitude,longitude data in global variable to use in other function?

***UPDATE: WHAT I EXACTLY NEED IS TO GET POSITION OF ALREADY CREATED MARKERS WITH FUNCTION ROUTE() hOW TO DO THAT:***

```
function route() {
      // Clear any previous route boxes from the map
      clearBoxes();

      // Convert the distance to box around the route from miles to km
      distance = parseFloat(document.getElementById("distance").value) * 1.609344;

      var request = {
        origin: document.getElementById("from").value,
        destination: document.getElementById("to").value,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      }

      // Make the directions request
      directionService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);

          // Box around the overview path of the first route
          var path = result.routes[0].overview_path;
          var boxes = routeBoxer.box(path, distance);
          drawBoxes(boxes);
        } else {
          alert("Directions query failed: " + status);
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: yes but again is the same

Comment: you can also declare your variable as global with window.startLocation="myStartLocation"; and when you want to display it: console.log(window.startLocation);

Comment: please explain me in code...

Comment: @MarcoJordan when you are declaring your variable var startLocation; do window.startLocation.

Comment: try creating the objects `startLocation` and `endLocation` outside/before the function and leave them to fill inside the function. this way you will have access to them, and will be accessible in console.log and other functions

Comment: but I declate this as startLocation = new Object();
  endLocation = new Object();

Comment: why when I type console.log(startLocation.latlng); I dont get result???

Comment: because you are trying to access object which is created inside function and it's not globally accessable.

Comment: @MarcoJordan here you can see how it works. http://jsfiddle.net/yMGuR/

Comment: here you can see, I dont get anything

Comment: @MarcoJordan dont you see the jsfiddle link?  http://jsfiddle.net/yMGuR/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not usually a very good idea to use global variables in any programming language, including javascript. Ideally, you should declare the variables you want to access both inside your function and in other functions on the outer scope.

For example, lets say your code is like this.

```
var valueOne;
function setValue(){
    valueOne = 3;
}
function readValue(){
    console.log(valueOne);
}
setValue();
readValue();
```

Will log "3" only if setValue is called before readValue. In this case, you have to be 100% sure that the variable is declared in a scope that contains both functions, and that they are called in that order.

Another way, adapting your own code, would be to use window.startLocation, window.endLocation, etc and that will attach your variables to the window object, making them globally available. By default in javascript using a variable without prepending `var` (`var startLocation`) should make it global, but if that is not working, then you can try attaching it to the window object directly. In any case, what you must make sure is that the function that sets the values you want to log to use in the other function is called before the other, if it isn't the values obviously won't be set.

Comment: Updated question is with my real problem, how to get postion of already created markers

Answer (score -1):

startLocation is a local variable to this function. You need to return it from here to access from other function. Or, use class scope. Read any standard book on javascript for this. You can also make it global but, I dont recommend it.